# Will washi tape adhesive leave residue overtime if it stays on a surface for a while?

Tags: adhesives

Supposedly washi tape doesn't leave residue, but what if it's in the heat or just stays on something for a long time? Will it still leave residue like all tapes overtime?

Comment: What would be also interesting to know is if it is, what are the alternatives.

Comment: I don't believe there are alternatives, washi tape is basically one of the most residue free tapes out there, so if it does leave residue from staying for a long time on something then I don't believe any other tape wouldn't. 

What I'd like to know if anyone here who used it has noticed it does.

Answer (score 8):

Not everything sold as washi tape is the same.  According to an article by a washi tape seller, [What is WASHI tape?](https://www.washitape.com/blogs/craft-project-ideas/what-is-washi-tape), washi tape from Japan is made by a few companies, possibly licensed by the developer, and has consistent, high quality.  There is also washi tape manufactured in China that has very variable quality, including big differences in adhesive characteristics.  There are brands from the US and a few other countries, but these may be manufactured in China.

Beyond that, while "real" washi tape can be made with paper from some different plant sources than is used in making washi paper, there is also tape based on tissue paper or other materials, like fabric, that is sold as washi tape but isn't.  There are also "washi" tapes with various coatings.  So it makes sense to limit the answer to the "authentic", Japanese paper product with consistent characteristics.

The adhesive is removable and repositionable, which typically is better at not leaving residue regardless of the adhesive substance.  According to [What does washi tape do?](https://wikilivre.org/culture/what-does-washi-tape-do/), the adhesive is made from natural rubber.  It's very good at being cleanly removable without damaging the surface, but at least some brands can leave small lines of adhesive residue if it remains in place for a long time.

So the bottom line is that you shouldn't count on washi tape never leaving any residue unless someone reports a particular brand used on the same surface material, left in place for more than say a year, and they were still able to remove it without leaving any residue.

Comment: I see, thank you!